# Apache CSV Quote Character Does Not Work For Multiple Columns

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

I read a very simple CSV file like this:

```java
String csv = "'ID', 'fruit'\n'1', 'apple'\n'2', 'banana'\n'3', 'cherry'";

try (InputStream resourceInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes());
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(resourceInputStream);) {

  CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',').withHeader()
          .withSkipHeaderRecord(false).withRecordSeparator("\n").withTrim().withQuote('\'');
  CSVParser parser = format.parse(inputStreamReader);
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iterator = parser.iterator();

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next.toMap());
  }
}
```

This prints the following to the console:

```
{ID=1, 'fruit'='apple'}
{ID=2, 'fruit'='banana'}
{ID=3, 'fruit'='cherry'}
```

While I of course expect:

```
{ID=1, fruit=apple}
{ID=2, fruit=banana}
{ID=3, fruit=cherry}
```

And it's not purely cosmetic either, if there is a separator inside the quotes it's used as if the quotes were not present. (So using "che,rry" will put "rry" in the third column.)

It does not work with " instead of ' either. It does not work with the default quote (which should be ", too). It does not work with `withQuoteMode()`. It does not work for the previous Apache CSV version (the current is 1.8, I tested 1.7 and 1.6).

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to make quotes work in the second and following columns?

**Nevermind:** It's working with `withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in header and value in the CSV text seem to confuse commons-csv, with the following string the output looks different:

Input:

```
String csv = "'ID','fruit'\n" +
    "'1','apple'\n" +
    "'2','banana'\n" +
    "'3','cherry'";
```

Output:

```
{ID=1, fruit=apple}
{ID=2, fruit=banana}
{ID=3, fruit=cherry}
```